# custom upload option not working

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, upload

am using magento 1.8.1 http://drugbazar.in/index.php/… this is my website url. I want to give image upload option in front end while upload an image it shows "**Please specify the product's required option(s).**" help me to fix this error

**Note:** Here am using custom file upload option for simple products.

Comment: What is the purpose of uploading an image to a drug?

Comment: to get prescription by image format for particular drugs

Answer (score -1):

It looks like indexing issue. Re-index your data and check again.

Comment: after re-indexing data facing same issue. does anyone knows how to fix this error